# Drupal 9 CK editor 5 does not render the code

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, ckeditor, ckeditor5

The CK editor 5 in Drupal 9.5 doesn't render the HTML and JS Code. It just displays the raw code.

Custom block code:

[image: Custom block code]

Rendered output:

[image: rendered output]

I tried two ways; one is default way provided by ck editor to add code which is shown in the image. The other way is a traditional way to add code. By choosing the source I put html and JS codes.In this way the special characters in JS code like "<", ">" are converted into escapes. So neither way is working.

Answer (score 0):

Similar the the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058455/147937), pasting the source into the main WYSIWYG window of CKEditor escapes some of the characters in the script tag, causing the code to render and not run. You need to first click on the "Source" option on the CKEditor toolbar (click the three vertical dots to see the option), then paste your Javascript in there.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of source option. I already added Js codes in Drupal 8. But with this Ckeditor 5 the source option makes this issue. @matt-v