# How to add inline JS code in Drupal CKEditor 5?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Trying to add my JS code to custom block in Drupal 9.5.3 with CKEditor 5. But JS code is not running there.

[image: custom block]

I tried adding code using code button in tool bar of CKEditor. But doesn't working.

In the older version of Drupal 8 I used to write the JS script in the custom blocks itself.

So, How can I add my JS scripts in editor itself?

Answer (score 1):

Here i tried my script without selecting option which is shown in your given image just clicking on source added js script
[image]

set text editor as full html this worked for me

Comment: Thank you, The code works but if i am using the special characters like "<", ">"...etc. The editor is changing into a unicode. For eg: if(a<b){my code here}. This < symbol is converted as a unicode value. And the code is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the source into the main WYSIWYG window of CKEditor escapes some of the characters in the script tag, causing it not to run. You need to first click on the "Source" option on the CKEditor toolbar (the right-most option in your screenshot), then paste your Javascript in there. I just tested pasting in some Javascript on a fresh install of Drupal 9.5.3 with CKEditor 5 on [simplytest.me](https://simplytest.me/) and it worked for me.

Comment: I also checked with CKEditor 5 on [simplytest.me](https://simplytest.me/) but it doesn't work. After writing JS code in Source tab. I saved the page and again went to check the JS code to check it. And there was no code. It's empty. The editor removed the JS code.  @Matt V.

Comment: [Js code works with equalto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTbnT.jpg)
[Js code with '<' or '>' doesn't run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZPV1.jpg)
[special chars changes to unicodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87gRx.jpg) after saving

user name:@matt-v

Comment: @vjprabhakar The bug that you're experiencing is being tracked here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3364884